# Mysql - Table structure

Tags: php, mysql

I want to implement a counting system as follows

```
     test_id   email_id      attemptCount   status   score   subject
        1       a@a1.com           1          Fail     5       C
        1       a@a1.com           1          Pass     72      maths
        1       b@a1.com           1          Pass     62      C
```

Just see, `(test_id,email_id, attempt_count, subject)`  forms unique row.

I want to insert a row for each test attempt. So attemptCount must be incremented by one for the `same user, same test id, same subject`.

**How Can I do?**

1) I can get the last attempt count for the key (test id, email id, subject) from another table

```
       test_id    email_id    subject   last_attempt
```

2) I can use triggers to auto increment attempt count. [I just read this way in one of the SO posts]

3) I have to change my table structure. So I will have separate table for my each subject. So primary key composition will be `test_id, email_id, attempt_count`

Is there any other way to achieve this? Which one is the best way to do?

I feel like I have to rethink about my table structure.

**EDIT**

Is it good practice to have multiple values in single cell as follows?

```
     test_id  email_id   overallStatus              overallScore  subject
        1      a@a1.com     [pass,fail,fail,pass]   [10,2,3,10]     maths
```

Then there will be only one row for the combination `(test_id, email_id, subject)`. I don't care about attemptCount in this case.

My aim is that I want to store all the attempt results for all the tests of all the users.

Comment: What exactly is `attemptCount` storing that can't be derived from simply counting the rows?

Comment: `attemptCount` is actually test attempt number. I am trying to achieve this in single query

Comment: Alternatively, you can use MyISAM for this (although there is a good argument for not 'storing' the 'count' at all).

Comment: @David, Strawberry please see my edits

Comment: @GopsAB: No, it is not good practice to have multiple values in a single field.  That would only make queries and data management more difficult.  It's still not really clear what the issue is here.  It seems like `attemptCount` is just storing the `COUNT()` of unique rows, which you don't really need to store since you can always just fetch it.  (In fact, what would happen if `attemptCount` was out of sync with the actual count?  Storing information that can be easily derived can be problematic.)

Comment: @David Yes I could use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` if I just read. My aim is that I have to insert a row for each attempt. Without having previous attempt number, how can I insert attemptCount?

Comment: @GopsAB: That's my point, you don't *need* to track `attemptCount`.  Insert a record for each attempt.  Any time you need to know how many attempts have been made, count the records.  You don't need to store the number of records you've inserted because that information is already available by the very existence of the records themselves.

Comment: @David You meant to say, I don't need to have `attemptCount` as a separate column. Then How can I identify a row uniquely? If I miss `attemptCount`, just see there can be any number of rows of the combination `test_id, email_id, subject`.

Comment: @GopsAB: Store a timestamp for each attempt.  That would uniquely identify them, provide means of sorting them chronologically, etc.  Basically, store information that the database needs rather than information the database provides.

Comment: I agree with @David. A good practice when figuring out what to store in your database is to leave out the stuff you can _easily_ calculate.  A table that stores the `test_id` and `email_id` can be easily counted to get the attempt count.  In your method the number of `UPDATE` queries grows by _n_ attempts.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use 3 tables.

test , subject and test_result

Id have test like this

```
test_id
email_id
//other columns such as date, description, etc
```

table subject

```
subject_id (auto_increment)
test_id
attempts
//you can add date and the latest status or score
```

This will be like an historical table, in case you want a report:

test_result

```
test_result_id(auto increment)
test_id
subject
status
score
```

So, when you make an insert on test_result you can update subject with a +1 on attempt (from table subject), and if you want to update the latest result on that table (to avoid making a query on this table which could be very long, you can do it too)

Answer (score 0):

Your methods/functions will have to be created in some sort of programming method, you won't be able to achieve all of this only passing in data to your Database.

You're correct about using an auto_increment on your test_id however, your primary key would be your test_id.

There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the primary key can still be a composite key even with an auto-incrementing field.

Comment: Yes, it could be: it only depends on if it's necessary.

Comment: Some confusion over the use use of the term "auto-incrementing" - there is no MySQL autoincrement data type in the proposal above. Its simple to add a unique constraint to the test_id,email_id, attempt_count, subject, and to specify the behaviour for handling duplicates in the DML (INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE....)

Comment: There is a way to auto-increment... You should consider upgrading your SQL software